# MediaRecorder output video not valid

Tags: android, video, android-camera, android-mediarecorder

I'm successfully recording a video with Android's MediaRecorder. The thing is, right after the video is recorded and outputted to the file declared with setOutputFile(), the video cannot be played.

I'm either getting a "Sorry, this video cannot be played" or "Media type not supported" error immediately after recording. However, if I record ***another*** video right after that one, and navigate back to the directory where the previous one is stored..the first video plays just fine.

I'm also noticing that trying to extract metadata from the video immediately after I record it is almost impossible, because both the file path and Uri pointing to the video come back invalid.

Any idea why this is? Basically, I'm capturing the video fine. But I just cannot access it or it's metadata until I either record another video, or restart my device. I'm leaning towards it being an issue with MediaScanner, but I'm not sure. Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!